# noticed gem with slack testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i'm using noticed gem with have connected this with database and with email ,this is working fine

```
deliver_by :slack, debug: true


 Notification Load (7.4ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 50], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      [ActiveJob] [Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Slack] [8f3f8423-81e7-4d46-86bc- 
   edafda6cd3e8] Performing Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Slack (Job ID: 8f3f8423-81e7- 
  4d46-86bc-edafda6cd3e8) from Async(default) enqueued at 2022-10-19T07:41:34Z with 
    arguments: {:notification_class=>"Commentnotification", :options=>{:debug=>true}, 
    :params=>{:comment=>#<GlobalID:0x00007fcce701d0e0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://fyp-ed- 
   bolt/Comment/20>>, :inquest=>#<GlobalID:0x00007fcce0c7b910 @uri=#<URI::GID 
  gid://fyp-ed-bolt/Inquest/1>>}, :recipient=>#<GlobalID:0x00007fcce70160d8 @uri=#. 
 <URI::GID gid://fyp-ed-bolt/User/1>>, :record=>#<GlobalID:0x00007fcce4fea7f0 @uri=#. 
<URI::GID gid://fyp-ed-bolt/Notification/50>>}
[ActiveJob] [Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Slack] [8f3f8423-81e7-4d46-86bc-edafda6cd3e8] 
Error performing Noticed::DeliveryMethods::Slack (Job ID: 8f3f8423-81e7-4d46-86bc- 
     edafda6cd3e8) from Async(default) in 265.87ms: NoMethodError (undefined method 
 `[]' for 
nil:NilClass):
```

but getting this error while connecting with slack.

Comment: Post your code. You are calling a method on a nil object: `NoMethodError (undefined method 
 `[]' for 
nil:NilClass)`

Comment: I have not set up things for slack, for emails, I did it through action cable I don't know how slack works with this notice gem, I'm having trouble while testing this. I'm new to rails might sound dumb, I'll appreciate it if you explain the process lill bit

Comment: Post some code, without it we can't help you